# how to Show all Table Rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

Everyday I have to copy and paste all data from a webpage's tables into Excel; there are more than 100 tables, each table contains 10 rows, each row is a link. When I click on it  it will expand and shown its content, but when I click on the 2nd row , the 1st row content will hide automatically, and when I click on the 3rd row, the 2nd row and other content also will hide automatically...

So I need to click the row 1 by 1 in order to show its contents and copy paste into excel, which is tedious and time consuming.

Is there any method that will cause the webpage expand all its tree contents when I open the webpage, or cause the link to not hide its contents automatically when I click on the other link? Here is an website example:

I have ask my boss for permission to log in and share his data , this is my extra job i need work for him.

this table consists of 10 rows , each of its 1st cell is link , when i open the website , the contents of 10 rows are all hidden , when i click on the 1st cell in 1st row , the 1st row HTML will show as:

```
<tr class="shown">
<td colspan="4" class="betslip cc" id="6088535226">
    <input type="hidden" name="maxwin" value="4133000" xmlns:histman="urn:histman">
    <input type="hidden" name="tOType" id="tOType" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="txtBetConfirmBankerData" id="txtBetConfirmBankerData" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="txtBetCountBanker" id="txtBetCountBanker" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="txtBetCountNonBanker" id="txtBetCountNonBanker" value="1">
    <table id="betSlip" class="bst" xmlns:histman="urn:histman">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="details">
                    <table id="tblHeading" class="bsdt" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="nbt">
                                <td class="nbr first" style="background-image: url(/MEMBERS/images/common/history/table-header-2.gif); background-repeat: repeat-x;"> <span class="b f11 nobr inblock">Bet Confirmation
    &nbsp;-&nbsp;SH3084343910F
      &nbsp;-&nbsp;Flash
    &nbsp;
  </span>
```

Time of bet: 
        04/02/2014 06:39:26

```
                                </td>
                                <td class="print last" style="background-image: url(/MEMBERS/images/common/history/table-header-2.gif); background-repeat: repeat-x;"> <a href="#" onclick="javascript: BetConfirm.OnPrintClick(); return false;">Print</a>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="subheading" class="lft nbt subheading">
                <td>Selections</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="details">
                    <table id="tblNormal" class="bsdt">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="header nbb">
                                <th class="ctr c38 first" style="background-image: url(/MEMBERS/images/common/history/table-header-2.gif); background-repeat: repeat-x;">No.</th>
                                <th class="lft c171 mid" style="background-image: url(/MEMBERS/images/common/history/table-header-2.gif); background-repeat: repeat-x;">Selections</th>
                                <th class="lft c208 mid" style="background-image: url(/MEMBERS/images/common/history/table-header-2.gif); background-repeat: repeat-x;">Event</th>
                                <th class="ctr c78" style="background-image: url(/MEMBERS/images/common/history/table-header-2.gif); background-repeat: repeat-x;">Event Date</th>
                                <th class="ctr c71" style="background-image: url(/MEMBERS/images/common/history/table-header-2.gif); background-repeat: repeat-x;">E/W Terms</th>
                                <th class="ctr c59" style="background-image: url(/MEMBERS/images/common/history/table-header-2.gif); background-repeat: repeat-x;">Odds</th>
                                <th class="ctr c61 last" style="background-image: url(/MEMBERS/images/common/history/table-header-2.gif); background-repeat: repeat-x;">Result</th>
                            </tr>
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtPartTypes" value="N,">
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtPDPitchersID" id="txtPDPitchersID">
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtPDTeam1ID" id="txtPDTeam1ID">
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtPDTeam2ID" id="txtPDTeam2ID">
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtPDBetSlipPartID" id="txtPDBetSlipPartID">
                            <tr class="nbb">
                                <td class="rgt first">1</td>
                                <td class="lft">高于 9.0</td>
                                <td class="lft">维拉利尔队 v 奥萨苏纳队
                                    <br>(附加角球总数)</td>
                                <td class="ctr">04/02/2014</td>
                                <td class="ctr">None</td>
                                <td class="ctr" nowrap="nowrap">11.00</td>
                                <td class="ctr last">Lost</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="nbb">
                                <td colspan="8" class="first last b">Stake:&nbsp; 16.00 &nbsp; Returns:&nbsp; 0.00 &nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="noteToWin" xmlns:histman="urn:histman">'Return' values are subject to maximum payouts as detailed in our rules.</div>
</td>
```

this is the shared link http://jsfiddle.net/engchiang/ghP2a/6/
the HTML of the 1st row will show as: tr class="shown" , the other 9 rows HTML will show as: tr class="hidden"

and then i click on the 1st cell in 2nd row , the 1st row HTML will show as:

```
<tr class="hidden" disabled="true">
<td colspan="4" class="betslip cc" id="6088535226"></td>
```

this is the shared link http://jsfiddle.net/engchiang/ghP2a/7/
the 1st row contents will then hide automatically , the HTML of the 2nd row will show as: tr class="shown" , and the HTML of the 1st row will show as: tr class="hidden" disabled="true"

then when i click on 1st cell in 3rd row , it show the 3rd row contents and hide the other row contents...

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing the page it's not possible to help.  We need to see the html structure.

Comment: without see how the page is hiding and showing tree content. It could be server side or it could be client side.Could not help much

Comment: the only thing I can suggest is to disable javascript...if this website don't load data asynchronously then you will see all the data...

Comment: 1) open the page in chrome. 2) hit F12, 3) right click on row 2 and choose "Inspect element", 4) paste the html of row 1, 2 and 3 into jsfiddle.net, removing any private data. Save and link to the jsfiddle here

Comment: It could be something simple like a bookmarklet with `javascript:(function() { $("a").each(function() { $(this).parent().addClass("active") }))()`

Comment: somebody please help me, i need to work for my boss extra 1,2 hours everyday and cannot be claim.